# How to load a greyed-out background after an On change form submission

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to put a greyed-out background upon form submission. The difference here is that I don't have a submit button, as I'm submitting the form after the user selects an option from one of 3 drop down lists.

Form sample:

```
<form action="{{route('cats.filter')}}" method="post" id="myform">
```

Select sample :

```
<select class="custom-select"  name="goalcat" id="goalcat" onchange="this.form.submit();">
```

Since I'm adding the Id of the form in the JS code, it is partially working, where the body is greyed out and the loading button is showing, but only when the user opens any of the drop down lists, and before selecting any option. I need to put a valid ID for the JS code so that it shows the greyed-out background after submitting.

JS :

```
  $("#myform").click(function () {
    $(".overlay").show();
});
```

CSS:

```
.overlay {
    background: #e9e9e9;  
    display: none;        
    position: absolute;   
    top: 0;                  
    right: 0;             
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is code using javascript:

```js
function submitForm(){
var form = document.getElementById('myform');
form.submit();
var overlay = document.getElementById('overlay');
overlay.style.display = 'block';

}
```

```css
#overlay {
  position: fixed; /* Sit on top of the page content */
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  width: 100%; /* Full width (cover the whole page) */
  height: 100%; /* Full height (cover the whole page) */
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); /* Black background with opacity */
  z-index: 2; /* Specify a stack order in case you're using a different order for other elements */
  cursor: pointer; /* Add a pointer on hover */
}
```

```html
<form action="" method="post" id="myform">
    <select class="custom-select"  name="goalcat" id="goalcat" onchange="submitForm();">
       <option value=""> ABC </option>
       <option value=""> XYZ </option>
       <option value=""> LMCV </option>
       <option value=""> AFA </option>
    </select>
</form>

<div id="overlay"></div>
```